# Integral $n$ for $\sin^n(x) + \cos^n(x) = 1-\frac{n}{2}\sin^2(x)\cos^2(x)$

Tags: functions, trigonometry

Show that only integral solution of $\sin^n(x) + \cos^n(x) = 1-\frac{n}{2}\sin^2(x)\cos^{2}(x)$ is $n=4,6$.

I have proved for $n=4,6$ it is true, for other integer, I tried to check range of functions on left and right side. This is not as effective, and I failed. Please suggest a method in this.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

$x=\pi/4$ gives
$$
\frac{1}{2^{n/2-1}}= 1-\frac{n}{8}
$$
and the RHS goes to $-\infty$ where LHS goes to $0$ as $n\to \infty$.

Comment: So we get $n < 8$

Comment: And we get more - if $n$ is odd, LHS is irrational.

Answer (score 4):

If you plug $x=\dfrac{\pi}{4}$, you will get:

$$\dfrac{2}{\sqrt{2}^n}=1-\dfrac{n}{8}.$$

Your left hand side is positive, so your right hand side should be as well, which imposes $n< 8$.

Now, if $n$ is odd, your left hand side is not rational, so you are left to check for $2,4,6$.

If $n=2$, the equality does not hold. Since you checked that $n=4,6$ work , we are done.

[Edit: $n$ replaced by $x$ on the first line]

Comment: @Peter: the question of the OP is not quantified in $x$, so I interpreted the question as an equality between to real functions over $\mathbb{R}$.

Comment: @Gregin.All is well.